# Declare/use variable in gradle file - use it in java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have in my gradle file something like :

```
String packageName = com.test.free
```

I want this String variable packageName to use in my java class. I use Android Studio 1.5.1.

Is it possible? How can I transfer this String from gradle to java ?

I have read similar questions here but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that value is really your `applicationId`, that is already available to you as `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

Otherwise, you can [add your own custom fields to `BuildConfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518940/custom-fields-for-a-build-type-in-gradle/24519195?s=7%7C0.2858#24519195). These can include dynamic values:

```
import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO", '"'+randomUUID()+'"'
        } 

        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO", '"a49f05b4-f55a-4066-a107-9098c9350f43"'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I have given that value as an example. I have some other data I need to access.

Comment: BuildConfig I can`t use because the accessed value must be hardcoded. The Value I am reading is dynamic and I am reading it from a String. Is there something like when transferin java String value to native via jni bridge?

Comment: @AdrianIvasku: "because the accessed value must be hardcoded" -- I don't think so. It has to be properly formatted (e.g., wrap a string value in quotes), but AFAIK it can be generated dynamically via a Groovy expression. "Is there something like when transferin java String value to native via jni bridge?" -- no, for the simple reason that Gradle and Groovy are not on the Android device.

Comment: @AdrianIvasku: See the updated answer for an example of a dynamically-generated value.

Comment: It works! Maybe Gavriel`s solution is correct too, but I have a confirmation for this one. My fault, I haven`t mentioned that I use experimental gradle so my solution is like this : buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    type = "String"
                    name = "packageName"
                    value = '"'+packageName+'"'
                }
            }         And then call it from java BuildConfig.packageName. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Create a gradle task that writes packageName into a java file like:

build.gradle:

```
task generateGradleValuesJava {
    def java = 
      'public class GradleValues {' +
      '  public static String packageName = "' + project.packageName+ '";' +
      '  }' +
      '}'
    def javaFile = new File('GradleValues.java')
    javaFile.write(java)
}

compileJava.dependsOn generateGradleValuesJava
```

Compile this file into your jar and use it:

```
GradleValues.packageName
```

Comment: I think I understand it now. I`l try this.