# Getting app configuration from a file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need to get some Config from a file probably an `xml` file to create build . I can not use `buildVarient` because build varients are not fixed. Below are the attributes i need to import.

1. Application ID:- In build.gradle.
2. BASE URL :- base url for network request.
3. App Name :- Application name in manifest

Requirement is one apk will be created for one person . SO the build procedure should be simple. Thats why i am thinking about to create a `config` file and reference all 3 attributes above from file.
Is it even possible for all of 3? If yes how? . Please help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using in `build.gradle` in flavors something like that:

```
Properties versionProps = new Properties()
versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('config.conf')))
def properties_versionCode = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
def properties_versionName = versionProps['VERSION_NAME']

versionName properties_versionName
versionCode properties_versionCode
```

Please take a look at 2nd, 3rd and 4th line.

Here is the `config.conf` file:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.0
VERSION_CODE=100
```

Both files should be placed in the same folder level.

---

For setting application names and base url I would use separate project folders, more discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785270/how-to-change-app-name-per-gradle-build-type).

---

You could also create custom build fields so it would be visible in code by calling `BuildConfig.{FIELD}`.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    buildConfigField "String", "OS", '"android"'
}
```

Then the BuildConfig looks like this:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.app";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
    // Fields from default config.
    public static final String OS = "android";
}
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454775/619673).

Comment: Fair enough . Where should i use `Properties versionProps = new Properties()`? Can you pls add the whole code block .

Comment: Also where should i put `config.properties` file . I used assets for it and i am getting `unable to resolve class android.content.res.AssetManager` in build.gradle?

Comment: Ok So i put `config.properties` under `app` folder . Its working in gradlle . Thx to You Bud . How can i access it in a java class ? And yeah Congratulations on 6K mission accomplish .

Comment: Can i use this file in assets ? If yes then how will i load it in `build.gradle`

Comment: `config.conf` is used only for `build.gradle` at the same folder level. Declared field from `buildConfigField` can be used in code by calling  `BuildConfig.{YOUR_FIELD}`. You must firstly rebuild project.

Comment: I used it in assets. Its working . Using `versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('/src/main/assets/configs/config.properties')))` . Thx for your support . I need to one question here please look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733808/how-to-read-a-config-file-which-is-under-app-folder).